# Move an object in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a circle move in the screen constantly and I would like to know how. I have this simple code:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // create the Paint and set its color
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        boolean flag = true;
        float i = 200;
       while ( flag ){
            if(i<800)i += 1;
                else if (i <0) i += 1; 
                   else i -=1;
           canvas.drawCircle(i, 200, 100, paint);
           canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
           }
    }

}
```

and a simple main activity which calls it.

Problem is that onDraw just paint something when finish and I dont know how to call onDraw again ( I know this very example never ends )

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know how to call onDraw again

You need `Handler` inside your view and `Runnable` posted to your handler that would trigger the redraw by calling `invalidate()`. Once runnable finished*, it should `postDelayed()` itself to the same handler to keep perpetum mobile running :) Naturally you may need to add some logic to stop on parent's `onPause()` or whatever.

*) theoretically, you should rather post itself on very beginning of the execution of your runnable to keep "tick" somehow ticking even, no matter how long it takes to handle the whole job, but that poses the risk, esp. if you try to "tick" too often, that your next one starts executing before current finished. But that's lest as exercise.

Comment: Thank you, I am starting with this and i dont get it perfectly, could you show it to me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the view's method invalidate. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

> To force a view to draw, call invalidate().